# Unable to convert bytes Uint8Array to string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, byte

I am unable to decrypt this Uint8Array

```
Uint8Array(32) [
    174, 157, 255, 238,  54, 143,  97, 132,
     70, 243,   7, 249,  98, 188,  68, 170,
     53,  82,  78,   9,  96, 226, 182, 160,
    131,  79,   3, 147, 153,  34, 205, 162
  ]
```

using this code

```
const string = new TextDecoder().decode(hash);
console.log(string);
```

I get this: `����Kc2Jk�&an↕�9���&��h-Lﺠ�Ԋ`

I've also tried with many online converters but it says there's some problem with the byte array. This byte array is a response from an API.

Where Am I wrong? How can I convert it properly?

Comment: Those bytes are no text what did you expect? Hex encoded?

Comment: What is the response supposed to represent? It doesn't correspond to normal plaintext utf-8, and, I'd hazard, any plaintext, because there's such a wide range of values in your array: the alphabet plus capitals is only about 60 different bytes, whereas your response has a range of 200, so you're encoding other kinds of information too. If it's a hash value, that makes sense, because you won't have it corresponding to some readable message. If all you want is to be able to print it out, try converting it to hex or base64 encoding:) Let me know if you need that explaining differently:)

Comment: @whatf0xx thank you so much. The response was supposed to represent a hash. What I did was to convert it to base64 and then to convert the base64 to hex and the results looks like this `AE9DFFEE368F618446F307F962BC44AA35524E0960E2B6A0834F03939922CDA2`. God bless you!

Comment: No problem! As a heads up, that conversion to base64 isn't necessary, you should be fine going straight from bytes to hex;)